# Should I choose API Gateway cache of DAX for a mobile app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am building a backend for  a mobile app. My architetcure incudes :
Client -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB

AWS provides caching at multiple levels. You can implement a cache at the API Gateway or DynanoDB level. With DynamoDB you can use DAX. My app is ready heavy. I am confused where should I cache, the options are:
 1. Cache at the API Gateway level
 2. Cache at DynamoDB using DAX
 3. Cache at both API Gateway and DAX

I think #3 is best. If the response can be returned by API Gateway, Lambda does not even need to run and hence low cost.

What is the preferred architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends how your app is used.

Are request responses unique based on user/API key? If so if the request isn't hit often there's probably no point caching in API Gateway.

Is the same data being retrieved from DynamoDB frequently? If so then DAX is great. However, it is more expensive so be aware of that.

Personally I'd try to keep my caching to one level if I could, just to avoid confusion that can occur from caching :)

Comment: Theer is global data which is user agnostic, such as top players leaderboard, etc.